# Does one need to adjust for multiple comparisons when using MANOVA?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, manova, bonferroni

There are 10 dependent variables and 2 groups. When I wanted to compare 10 dependent variables between two groups, I performed MANOVA.

I wonder if there is a multiple comparison problem in that case. Should I have performed Bonferroni correction because of 10 dependent variables? Or is Bonferroni useless because MANOVA just does analysis once?

Comment: I think you mean *dependent variables* when you say "independent variables". A dependent variable is a response or outcome, whereas an independent variable is an explanatory or predictor variable.

Comment: You're right, I made mistake. So, now I correct the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for correction.

Think about it like that: you could conduct 10 independent ANOVAs for each of the 10 dependent variables (in case of only 2 groups ANOVA reduces to t-test, but it does not matter for this question). Then you would get 10 different p-values, and certainly would need to correct for multiple comparisons, e.g. by applying Bonferroni correction. But if you use MANOVA, then you get only one single p-value and so there is no need for any corrections. The test is done by considering all 10 variables together, so there is no "multiple testing" (meaning that you are not doing any test "multiple times").

Comment: I think you mean *dependent variables* when you say "independent variables". A dependent variable is a response or outcome, whereas an independent variable is an explanatory or predictor variable. This answer is correct; in addition, you might want to talk about whether or not corrections for multiple testing are needed for 10 follow-up ANOVAs if the initial MANOVA is significant, though.

Comment: @gung: Yes, you are right: I was confused by the same terminological mistake in the original question. I will correct it now. Regarding your additional question: actually I don't know what the best practice is. I would be very interested myself if you could briefly explain.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to adjust the alpha level of the MANOVA test itself, as amoeba noted. However, a significant MANOVA doesn't allow you to make statements about any of your 10 DVs--that would require conducting individual *t*-tests, which *would* require correcting for multiple comparisons.